# Can I merge a Facebook company page and an application?

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-apps

I already have a page for my company that has more than 240 friends. On the other hand I recently started to develop a Facebook App (that has the same name) to use the Graph API from my company's website. The problem is that I don't want to lose my fans nor start again ads campaign, etc.
Is there any way to merge those two or make an Facebook App from the company's page?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Facebook doesn't support it from standard interface. But, Facebook can merge your page with app if you contact them. Facebook once accepted my request few years ago.

240 isn't a big number. So, its likely that they wouldn't listen. But, go try.. specially when your company has big offline profile.

In case you're out of luck, post the link of app on page with catchy words many times. It can draw attention of existing fans. And, if they are really fan, they'd like your app for sure.

Put link of app on welcome tab of page, too. Its for your existing ad campaigns.

Answer (score 1):

You can invite them with the Firefox script:

```
javascript:elms=document.getElementsByName("checkableitems[]");for (i=0;i<elms.length;i++){if (elms[i].type="checkbox")elms[i].click()};
```

There does not seem to be a way to merge them, only invite and at that the code seems to not be flawed, but Facebook doesn't allow bulky invite requests so you will have to repeat the script, which is faster than clicking on them over and over and will take you five minutes or so to invite them all.

Here is where I got it: http://www.facebook.com/selectallfriendsmozilla/info

Also from experience I know Facebook doesn't allow bulky requests, at least not for me. I did this a few days ago myself requesting all my friends to like a page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to create a new webpage to extract the Graph Statistics from your Facebook API and provide links to your fan page if your page is a Facebook page.  So far there is no way out to combine such two things into one. It is just because  Facebook doesn't allow bulky invite requests.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way currently to merge these two pages.

Answer (score -1):

If you created the application from the same ID just invite all the friends to that application. Click on the dropdown icon on the top right corner next to Home button. Then click on *Use Facebook as 'Your application's name'*. After the application's page is loaded then invite all your friends to the application.

Above the Cover Page there will be an option to *invite friends*. Click on those that you want to invite to your application.